# Fuchsian groups and surface groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

The following question may be trivial or inappropriate; I am not sure though.

It is known that a cocompact oriented Fuchsian group $\Gamma$ admits a presentation: for given $m,g,d_i \geq 0$
$$
\Gamma := \langle x_1, \ldots, x_m , y_1, \ldots, y_g, z_1, \ldots, z_g | x_1^{d_1}, \ldots ,x_m^{d_m}, x_1 \ldots x_m [y_1,z_1] \ldots [y_g,z_g] \rangle
$$
In the case where $m =0$ and $g > 1$ one obtains surface group of genus $g$. 
The question is whether there are homomorphisms with interesting properties between Fuchsian groups and surface groups, with the same genus $g$?

Comment: There's the retraction obtained by mapping all $x_i$ to 1. You can also compose (on the surface group side) by elements in the mapping class group/$\mathrm{Out}(\pi_1(\Sigma_g))$. Beyond that I don't see anything "natural" without changing genus.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any maps if the genus differs?

Comment: You get inclusion of a larger genus surface group into any cocompact Fuchsian group by "Selbergs lemma" (which probably has an easy topological proof in this case).

Comment: As @JeanRaimbault says, there's always a canonical map from a Fuchsian group to the fundamental group of the underlying surface, given by forgetting the orbifold structure (ie, in the given presentation, killing the $x_i$).  Note, this is *never* a `retraction' in the usual sense.  And then, of course, one can always naturally map a surface group to a surface group of smaller genus, either by compression (ie killing some $y_i,z_i$) or via a covering map.  (I'm pretty sure that *every* map between surfaces factors as a sequence of compressions and covering maps...

Comment: ...though I don't know a reference off the top of me head.)  If the target has larger genus, it's not hard to see that the image has to have infinite index, hence be free, and is therefore 'uninteresting' in some sense.  It's hard to know if these facts answer the question, since it's vaguely phrased.

Comment: If the two Fuchsian groups have the same genus g then the map is either surjective or its image has infinite index as a finite index subgroup corresponds to a higher genus orbifold and there is no surjective map from a Fuchsian group onto a surface group of higher genus (torsion elements need to lie in the kernel).

Comment: If the image has infinite index then it is virtually free. In the surface case this means that all of these maps factor through a free group of genus g (Makanin-Razborov diagram for surface groups). I would assume that there is a similar statement for understanding all homomorphisms from a fixed Fuchsian group into all virtually free groups.

Comment: ... that occur as subgroups of some other fixed Fuchsian group.